# react-native babel error Unknown option: .name?

Tags: react-native, babeljs, react-native-ios, versionupgrade

I recently updated my react version and I'm experiencing this issue.

```
index.js: [BABEL] /Users/ReactNative/Documents/use/app/index.js: Unknown option: .name. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.
```

Would anyone be able to offer me some advice?

It would be greatly appreciated if you could help.